# Postgres OS X 10.9.5

Tags: heroku, osx-mavericks, postgresql-9.3, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Humbly seeking assistance. Learning Ruby on Rails.

Watching this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EzzoULwWx8#t=480 and at 9:10 the instructor enters:

```
psql
```

The bash shell is different than mine and does not have the $ at the terminal prompt.

When I try:

```
Michels-MacBook-Pro:~ michelfrechette$ pqsl
```

These are my results:

```
Michels-MacBook-Pro:~ michelfrechette$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Michels-MacBook-Pro:~ michelfrechette$
```

Using: PostgreSQL 9.3.5

What am I missing? Can anyone offer guidance? Thank you.

Additional info:

```
Michels-MacBook-Pro:~ michelfrechette$ heroku --v
/Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `mkdir': ERROR:            Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ./.gem.20141013-60662-6x4qt9

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/michelfrechette/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-    p481@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/michelfrechette/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/executable-hooks-1.3.2/gem_make.out
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `block in mktmpdir'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:142:in `create'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `mktmpdir'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:14:in `build'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from /Users/michelfrechette/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:9:in `<main>'
```

Additional Info:

```
Michels-MacBook-Pro:~ michelfrechette$ ps -ef | grep postgres
501 60896 60710   0  6:06am ttys000    0:00.00 grep postgres

Michels-MacBook-Pro:~ michelfrechette$ gem install pg
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/michelfrechette/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-   p481@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ./.gem.20141013-60906-9b5gwl

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/michelfrechette/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-  p481@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/michelfrechette/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-   p481@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/executable-hooks-1.3.2/gem_make.out
(Gem::Ext::BuildError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/michelfrechette/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-  p481@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.5/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ./.gem.20141013-60906-m2ih6w

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/michelfrechette/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-   p481@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/michelfrechette/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-   p481@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/executable-hooks-1.3.2/gem_make.out
(Gem::Ext::BuildError)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.17.1
invalid options: -f fivefish
(invalid options are ignored)
Parsing documentation for pg-0.17.1
Done installing documentation for pg after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
Michels-MacBook-Pro:~ michelfrechette$
```

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL?

Did you check that PostgreSQL is running?

Comment: Your shell *does* have the `$` at the prompt. It just has a longer prompt. For this purpose a shell is a shell is a shell, anyway.

Comment: @CraigRinger - I am simply following along with the YouTube video. Not sure how PostgreSQL was installed. How do I check if PostgreSQL is running? I am not in a particular Rails project or connected to the Rails server, should I be?

Comment: Might be a good idea to explain the steps you took then. I doubt many people will want to watch a random tutorial video to try to figure out what you've been trying to do so far. To check if PostgreSQL is running: `ps -ef | grep postgres` is a start. It's nothing to do with Rails.

Comment: @CraigRinger Uncertain of particular steps taken. Added the results of `ps -ef | grep postgres` and edited them into my original question.

Comment: If you don't know what you did it's pretty hard to help you. It's clear Pg isn't running. You don't know if you even installed it, or if so, from where/how. Perhaps you haven't installed it, so it's not running? Or maybe the video assumes you're on an OS X version where the Apple-provided PostgreSQL is available? Or it assumes you've alread installed it per some prior instructions? *Shrug*. Can't help you, sorry.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Thank you for your patience. I have since downloaded the Postgres app from postgres.org. The app is in my Applications folder. Clicking on it yields an alert message “Postgres.app” can’t be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed."

Comment: ... and when you searched for the error message....? (Hint: new OS X releases require signed binaries by default).

Comment: @CraigRinger - Thank you for your guidance. I will continue hacking at it.